# Geo tools and other options?

Tags: maps, geo

This is my scenario. I have the latitude and longitude of certain places in a CSV file.I now want to be able to show these points on a map. say for example on the US map.I tried converting this CSV file to shape file and tried to use the geo-tools to do this, but am missing some jar file which am unable to figure out.What are the other good options for solving this problem?

Comment: how about google map? have you tried it before?

Comment: I haven't, could please point me to some resources?

Comment: I just tried it and could draw a simple map with a single map, but is it possible to put a lot of points on the map??

Comment: sorry single map with a sinle point, can i plot a lot of points?

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe take a look at [mapwindow](http://www.mapwindow.org/index.php) or [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org) if you just want to see the points on a map.